# Global.asax page ? In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application [asp.net] shall we write code that can retrive data from datbase or insert something in database. in any event of global.asax. when i am writing code in "Application_BeginRequest" even like :

Session["abc"]= 10; it is throwing exception that session can't declare some thing.Session state is not available in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. You need to read about [ASP.NET page cycle](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73728/ASP-NET-Application-and-Page-Life-Cycle)

Then You will realize that Session state is not available on BeginRequest

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I am understanding your question correctly then you are right that you cannot access session in that event. Try instead putting it in [Application.AcquireRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.acquirerequeststate.aspx). This is where ASP.NET sets up session and such like.

What you can use in `BeginRequest` is the [Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) which is acceesible in that request if you just need to set up data for just that request.